# ffmpeg: how to prevent wait in case of error

Tags: ffmpeg

I use **ffmpeg** to add watermark to images/videos, using the following command line:

```
ffmpeg -y -f mjpeg -i input -i /tmp/watermark.png -filter_complex "..." -f mjpeg output
```

The problem is, in case the input file is **not** a jpeg file, the process will **HANG** instead of quit with an error:

```
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mjpeg @ 0x126dc60] dqt: len 28602 is too large
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A
```

In my situation, the file has no extension, and I have to specify `-f`.  In case I got the file type wrong, it is an acceptable bug, which I can fix as soon as I found such problem.  However it is **not** good for me if ffmpeg hangs without returning to the parent process, because I have a very large queue of files to process, and I don't want any bug to block the processing task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how much the program takes on processing files you can use linux [timeout](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html#index-timeout) command, to cancel the execution of any program after such time.

You can also play around with the [-t option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options) in the ffmpeg command wich limits the time spent processing but the first option is better in my opinion.

Comment: so there is no way to quit immediately even when ffmpeg itself know that "Invalid data found when processing input"?

Comment: I haven't found one either, might exist, but if it doesnt end by itself for you might be an outdated version or just that it doesn't do that. You might be able to program a controller that checks if that has happened and kills that process when it does. But all the solutions i can think of are external to ffmpeg itself.